# Check if color is dark or light in Android

Tags: android, colors, background

as per title, my question is: Does Android provide any way to analyze/determine if a color (that will be obviously dynamic for the purpose) is light or dark?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Android doesn't provide it, you can implement a method to determine this. Here a method to do that:

```
public boolean isColorDark(int color){
    double darkness = 1-(0.299*Color.red(color) + 0.587*Color.green(color) + 0.114*Color.blue(color))/255;
    if(darkness<0.5){
        return false; // It's a light color
    }else{
        return true; // It's a dark color
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! goona try asap and report back!

Comment: from where did you get these magic numbers?? (0.299, 0.587, 0.114) ?

Comment: It's the definition of luminance for digital formats. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_%28video%29

Comment: Looks like android provide it https://stackoverflow.com/a/48267387/3940133

Comment: You're so smart dude, thanks for sharing your intelligence with us

Comment: `#000000` its work success, but `#FFFFFF`  return to me its dark color why..

Answer (score 100):

If you use support library v4 (or AndroidX), you can use `ColorUtils.calculateLuminance(color)`, which returns luminance of color as float between `0.0` and `1.0`.

So you can do something like:

```
boolean isDark(int color) {
    return ColorUtils.calculateLuminance(color) < 0.5;
}
```

See:

- Support library v4: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/ColorUtils.html#calculateLuminance(int)
- AndroidX: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/graphics/ColorUtils#calculateLuminance(int)

Note since Android API 24 there is also method: `Color.luminance(color)`.

Comment: Somehow `ColorUtils.calculateLuminance(color) < 0.25` worked better for me.

Answer (score 12):

In case one would like to find out whether background color is light or dark to determine what color to use for text drawn on top of it (white or black) – calculating luminance won't provide you correct value in all the cases.

Consider you have background color: `#7f6fad`.
If you check its luminance (via `ColorUtils#calculateLuminance`) you'll get: `0.1889803503770053`, which is below `0.5` and therefore should be considered as dark following that logic.

But if you follow [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#relativeluminancedef) you'll see that for general text contrast should be at least 4.5:1.

ColorUtils has method `calculateContrast` which will give the following results:

- For white text color: `4.393666669010922`
- For black text color: `4.779607007540106`

One can see that contrast which white text gives is not enough, while black is good.
Therefore if you'd like to check what color to draw on top of some generic background color it is better to check contrasts instead:

```
@ColorInt
fun getContrastColor(@ColorInt color: Int): Int {
    val whiteContrast = ColorUtils.calculateContrast(Color.WHITE, color)
    val blackContrast = ColorUtils.calculateContrast(Color.BLACK, color)

    return if (whiteContrast > blackContrast) Color.WHITE else Color.BLACK
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
public float getLightness(int color) {
    int red   = Color.red(color);
    int green = Color.green(color);
    int blue  = Color.blue(color);

    float hsl[] = new float[3];
    ColorUtils.RGBToHSL(red, green, blue, hsl);
    return hsl[2];
}
```

One could easily use the ColorUtils to check the lightness of a color.

```
if (getLightness(color) < 0.5f ){
    // This color is too dark!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
private static final int BRIGHTNESS_THRESHOLD = 130;

    /**
     * Calculate whether a color is light or dark, based on a commonly known
     * brightness formula.
     *
     * @see {@literal http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_color_space%23Lightness}
     */
    public static boolean isColorDark(int color) {
        return ((30 * Color.red(color) +
                59 * Color.green(color) +
                11 * Color.blue(color)) / 100) <= BRIGHTNESS_THRESHOLD;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying the accepted answer a little

```
public boolean isColorDark(int color){
    final double darkness = 1-(0.299*Color.red(color) + 0.587*Color.green(color) + 0.114*Color.blue(color))/255;
    return !(darkness<0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include `alpha` channel in calculations:

```
fun isColorDark(color: Int): Boolean {
    val darkness = (1 - (0.299 * Color.red(color) + 0.587 * Color.green(color) + 0.114 * Color.blue(color)) / 255) * (Color.alpha(color) / 255)
    return darkness >= 0.5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Kotlin** using **extension function** on `Int` type and with a darkness `threshold` parameter it can look like the following:

```
/**
 * Determines if this color is dark.
 * @param threshold - min darkness value; the higher the value, the darker the color;
 * float value between 0.0 and 1.0.
 */
fun Int.isColorDark(@FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0) threshold: Float = 0.9f): Boolean {
    val darkness = 1 - (Color.red(this) * 0.299 + Color.green(this) * 0.587 + Color.blue(this) * 0.114) / 255
    return darkness >= threshold
}
```