# Navigation bar buttons color

Tags: android, layout, uinavigationbar, galaxy

I want to change color of **navigation buttons** in my application, 
[image]

I tried with `window.setNavigationBarColor(@ColorInt int color)` but this method changing only background of bar. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change navigation bar icon color on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33104246/change-navigation-bar-icon-color-on-android)

Comment: Still no answer??

Comment: why no answer!!!

Answer (score 6):

You can change the navigation color dynamically using the following function. Basically it checks if the given NavigationBar background color is light or dark and sets the appropriate theme to the buttons. Setting a specific color to the buttons is not possible.

```
private void setNavigationBarButtonsColor(Activity activity, int navigationBarColor) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        View decorView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        int flags = decorView.getSystemUiVisibility();
        if (isColorLight(navigationBarColor)) {
            flags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR;
        } else {
            flags &= ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR;
        }
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
    }
}

private boolean isColorLight(int color) {
    double darkness = 1 - (0.299 * Color.red(color) + 0.587 * Color.green(color) + 0.114 * Color.blue(color)) / 255;
    return darkness < 0.5;
}
```

Comment: works fine, but how do you know that magic numbers for determining lightness of color?

Comment: I probably copy-pasted from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260853/check-if-color-is-dark-or-light-in-android which links to this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_%28video%29

Answer (score 2):

I know it's too late but still, for other people, here's how you can do it in your activity's `onCreate(...)`  method:

```
val windowInsetsController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)

//For status bar texts/icons color
windowInsetsController.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = true

//For navigation bar icons color
windowInsetsController.isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = true
```

Set them true or false as per your need. It won't affect the custom color of your navigation bar. You can set custom color for navigation bar like this:

```
window.navigationBarColor =
            context.getColorFromAttr(com.google.android.material.R.attr.colorPrimary)
```

and then create this kotlin extension function:

```
@ColorInt
fun Context.getColorFromAttr(
    @AttrRes attrColor: Int
): Int {
    val typedArray = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(intArrayOf(attrColor))
    val textColor = typedArray.getColor(0, 0)
    typedArray.recycle()
    return textColor
}
```